Undo git fetch --prune with explicit refs (undo deleting old local branches)
I used --prune without realizing that since I'm passing refs explicitly, it will remove them if there's no remote equivalent:
$ git fetch --prune . $(git for-each-ref --format='%(push):%(refname)' refs/heads --exclude="refs/heads/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)")

From .
 - [deleted]               (none)         -> armor-strip
 - [deleted]               (none)         -> attack-state
 - [deleted]               (none)         -> bugfix
 ! [rejected]              HEAD           -> armor-strip  (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]              HEAD           -> attack-state  (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]              HEAD           -> bugfix  (non-fast-forward)

(Was experimenting with git sync.)
I believe these were local-only branches that had never been pushed to the remote. I did not want remove them.
How can I recover them? git show bugfix@{1} fails. They are all months old, so do I have to use git log --reflog --oneline --graph to walk back in time to find orphaned commits? Is there a better way?

Deleting a ref also deletes the reflog for that ref. https://github.com/gitgitgadget/git/issues/236

@Schwern: It will if you pass them to it directly: git branch important ; git fetch --prune . :refs/heads/important ; git branch

@idbrii Wow,I stand corrected. It's even mentioned in the docs. "So be careful when using this with a refspec like refs/tags/:refs/tags/, or any other refspec which might map references from multiple remotes to the same local namespace."

First step: disable garbage collection so git doesn't toss our lost data.
git config --local gc.auto 0 

I did git branch -vvv -a and compared that against the [deleted] output to see what branches were really lost (not on any remote).
Thanks to @Guildenstern for the pointer that reflog wasn't going to help me because reflog entries are immediately deleted when deleting a ref. Instead, I followed this advice to use git fsck to find unreachable commits (ones that aren't associated with a name like a branch or tag). However, it dumps out sha hashes so I wrapped it in some python to have messages and author alongside the commit hashes:
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# filename: resolveunreachable.py
import re
from pathlib import Path
import sys

# Install with: pip install GitPython
import git

# To try to resolve faster, turn this off so we only look at commits.
TRY_HARDER = True

def dump_commits(repo, file, logpath):
    commits = []
    logs = []
    raw = []
    missing = []
    for line in file:
        # Lines look like:
        #   unreachable blob 3c001056f1402000000cd633e824b3d03276ac69
        m = re.match(r"\w+\s(\w+)\s([0-9A-Fa-f]+)$", line)
        kind = m.group(1)
        sha = m.group(2)

        if kind == "commit":
            c = repo.commit(sha)
            newline = "\n"
            firstline = c.message.split(newline, 1)[0]
            msg = f"{kind} by '{c.author}' {c.hexsha} {firstline}"
            commits.append(msg)
            # Commits are most relevant, so print as we find to show some progress.
            print(msg)

        elif TRY_HARDER:
            # Probably always fails because only commits have log?
            c = repo.git.log(sha, max_count=1, format="oneline", stat=True)
            if c:
                logs.append(f"{kind} {c}")
            else:
                # In desperation, dump the object (probably just shows first
                # lines of a file or first file in tree).
                c = repo.git.show(sha, oneline=True, stat=True)
                if c:
                    line_count = 3
                    parts = c.split("\n", line_count)
                    raw.append(f"{kind} {sha} {' '.join(parts[0:line_count])}")
                else:
                    missing.append(f"Cannot show {kind} {sha}")

    with logpath.open("w") as f:

        def dump(sep, msgs):
            f.write("\n")
            for item in msgs:
                try:
                    f.write(item)
                except UnicodeEncodeError as ex:
                    # I have some unicode in my commit messages and it barfed
                    # here. Hopefully those aren't the commits I'm looking for.
                    print(ex)
                f.write(sep)

        dump("\n", commits)
        dump("\n\n", logs)
        dump("\n", raw)
        dump("\n", missing)


root = Path(sys.argv[1])  # Or hardcode your repo path here.
repo = git.Repo.init(root)
logpath = root / "unreach_info.log"

# Created this file with this very slow command:
#   git fsck --unreachable  > fsck_unreachable.log
# Storing in a file to avoid waiting to regenerate it.
fpath = root / "fsck_unreachable.log"
with fpath.open("r") as f:
    dump_commits(repo, f, logpath)

Run it in your repo like so (both steps took a long time for me):
cd to/repo/root
git fsck --unreachable  > fsck_unreachable.log
python3 resolveunreachable.py to/repo/root

It writes an unreach_info.log file that looks like this (but with thousands of lines):
commit by 'idbrii' 6e1df09f8e180036995509ced40eabb738575c9d wip: start unreleased armor stripping
commit by 'idbrii' 4723c0846f87a17658fb7d0fe7890f5f5040ae10 wip: Partial conversion of monster talk into quips


blob ae0140b3c3f960ff9371972c110e3dbee16aecec return {^M  canopy_shadow={^M    { x=-9.34, z=-13.8 },^M
blob ef03904f4eab24ce9f4e1c19dd935883cff58aee from __future__ import absolute_import^M^Mimport logging^M
tree 14048018c5a620f93fca04f70ac195b129e18f76 tree 14048018c5a620c935ca04f70ac195b129e18f76 attack.lua

The first section with commits was sufficient for me to search the file for keywords related to my lost branches and find relevant commits. For each candidate commit, I checked its commits in context (using --graph to see multiple commits from the lost branch), recreated my lost branches, and immediately pushed them (in case I do something dumb like this again):
git log --graph --oneline 6e1df09f8e180036995509ced40eabb738575c9d
git branch armor-strip 6e1df09f8e180036995509ced40eabb738575c9d
git push mine armor-strip

Once I'd recovered all of my branches, I turned gc back on:
git config --unset --local gc.auto

